# Where is this Solidity mapping variable initialised?

Tags: ethereum, solidity

There is sample code in ["Modular Contracts"](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/solidity-by-example.html#modular-contracts) that uses a mapping, but I cannot see where that values of each mapping index get assigned.

The mapping is defined as:

```
mapping(address => uint256) balances;
```

and it is passed into the library function "Balances":

```
library Balances {
    function move(mapping(address => uint256) storage balances, 
        address from, 
        address to, 
        uint amount) internal {
            require(balances[from] >= amount);
            require(balances[to] + amount >= balances[to]);
            balances[from] -= amount;
            balances[to] += amount;
        ...
```

But I don't see where any value is actually initially added to `balances` in any part of the full [code example](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/solidity-by-example.html#modular-contracts).

The `move` function first checks if `balances[from] >= amount`. At the end of that function you see it adds and subtracts from the identified `balances`, but that code will never be reached, right? Since `require(balances[from] >= amount);` will always return false.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just an example of Modular Contracts you can add any balance in your constructor like

```
constructor() public {
  balances[yourAddress] = amount
}
```

Comment: Ok, thanks!. (I was just thinking since it was named "balances" it might've been a built-in function that returned the actual eth balance at that address.)